# Windows update causes User Profile Service issue on Vista but which update?

Tags: windows-vista

We have a Windows Vista laptop which has a problem with some recent MS update, causes the User Profile Service to fail to load and leaves the user with a black desktop and not much else.

Problem is there are currently sixty-six updates outstanding!  Install them all and the problem comes back, go back to restore point and all works fine.

How can I get a clue as to which of these 66 updates are causing the problem.

Edit: A bit more info in case it helps:

EventId: 1532 - The user service has stopped

Windows could not connect to the user profile service

Comment: I'd try bisecting. Install first half of updates. If everything works fine, then one of the other updates causes the issue - install first half of them. If the issue appears, then the broken update is in this batch; rollback and install first half of it. It's probably not the quickest method, but it always works. With 66 updates you'll be done in 7 tries tops.

Comment: Very long-winded, I didn't fancy having to make a list of which thirty updates were installed and which not.  Biggest problem is that MS Update server for Vista is ridiculously slow at the moment, taking 4-5 hrs to check for updates.

Comment: Checking for Updates is taking about FIVE hours!  Which in Vista needs to be done after each update before the next batch can be installed.  This could take months to install them all individually.

Comment: AFAIR there's an update that fixes that ;)

Comment: Ahh but which one is it!

Comment: Progress has been made, all but four updates now installed.

Problem is if any of these remaining four updates are installed the User Profile Service problem comes back again.  The problematic updates are:

    KB3112148
    KB3118401
    KB3140527
    KB2974269

Can anyone see any similarity in these which could cause the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the descriptions of these four updates :

1. KB3112148
   December 2015, cumulative time zone update for Windows operating systems
2. KB3118401
   The Windows 10 Universal CRT is a Windows operating system component that enables CRT functionality on the Windows operating system. This update allows Windows desktop applications that depend on the Windows 10 Universal CRT release to run on earlier Windows operating systems.
3. KB3140527
   This package will update Microsoft Security Essentials client on the user's machine.
4. KB2974269
   security update for the .NET Framework 3.0.
   This update resolves a vulnerability in the Microsoft .NET Framework that could allow denial of service if an attacker sends a few specially crafted requests to an affected .NET-enabled website.

I cannot see any similarity between these updates, except that they apparently
contain the same component which breaks your system.

Rather than trying to figure which component it is, I would try to do without them. In any case, you probably don't need numbers 2 and 4, and can do without
number 1 (at most you would need to manually correct the clock).
You could hide updates 1,2,4 to never see them again until new updates come out
to supersede them.

Number 3 is for Microsoft Security Essentials. You could maybe solve this by removing Microsoft Security Essentials, download the [latest version](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download) and reinstall.
Otherwise, get another free antivirus - many of them are better than
Microsoft Security Essentials.

I don't think Microsoft makes any effort today as regarding Vista support.
Keeping Vista working and up to date might require some effort.

Comment: Tried downloading and installing the latest MSE but the update still comes back.

Comment: In this case, I'm afraid you will need to give up on MSE.